# Having a panda data frame, output specific columns after condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda data frame in which its first column contains genomes of bacteria (names). On the other hand, I have a dictionary in which I have in the keys unknown names of bacteria and I have in the values bacterias that I know and these values are in my data frame.

I would like to create a new data frame with the unknown names in one column, then the know names in a second column and some columns of the previous data frame. Better see example.

My df

```
accession                  phylum           class       order          genus
1   bacteriaA   p__Firmicutes   c__Bacilli  o__Lactobacillales  g__Enterococcus
2   BacteriaB   p__Proteobacteria   c__Gammaproteobacteria  o__Pseudomonadales  g__Acinetobacter
```

My dict

```
{'GCF_001999625.1': ['bacteriaA'],
 'GCA_000307585.2': ['BacteriaC', 'BacteriaJ', 'BacteriaK'],
 'GCA_000404785.1': ['BacteriaB','BacteriaBP']}
```

How could I create something like this

```
unknown              accession.       phylum            class       order          genus
1   GCF_001999625.1 bacteriaA p__Firmicutes c__Bacilli  o__Lactobacillales  g__Enterococcus
2   GCA_000404785.1 BacteriaB p__Proteobacteria c__Gammaproteobacteria  o__Pseudomonadales  g__Acinetobacter
```

Basically what I am trying to get unlucky is to introduce queries and obtain as an output 4 columns in a comprehensible way.

Biologically speaking I want to make a relation between my unknown groups of bacteria with my know group.

I have spent many hours trying this but I don't know how to do it.

Could you please pass me some advice?

Comment: Does every known bacteria have only one unknown bacteria?

Comment: I would say yes

Answer (score 0):

I would first convert the dict into a DataFrame with 2 columns: the unknown name, and the Bacteria, and then do an inner merge into the initial DataFrame:

```
data = {'GCF_001999625.1': ['bacteriaA'],
 'GCA_000307585.2': ['BacteriaC', 'BacteriaJ', 'BacteriaK'],
 'GCA_000404785.1': ['BacteriaB','BacteriaBP']}

unk = pd.DataFrame([[k,j] for k, v in data.items() for j in v],
                   columns = ['unknown', 'accession'])

resul = unk.merge(df, on='accession')
```

`resul` is as expected:

```
           unknown  accession             phylum                   class               order             genus
0  GCF_001999625.1  bacteriaA      p__Firmicutes              c__Bacilli  o__Lactobacillales   g__Enterococcus
1  GCA_000404785.1  BacteriaB  p__Proteobacteria  c__Gammaproteobacteria  o__Pseudomonadales  g__Acinetobacter
```

Answer (score 0):

If every known bacteria has only one unknown bacteria, you should reverse your dictionary - have the known bacteria as keys and unknown as values:

```
{'bacteriaA': 'GCF_001999625.1',
'BacteriaC': 'GCA_000307585.2',
'BacteriaJ': 'GCA_000307585.2',
'BacteriaK': 'GCA_000307585.2',
'BacteriaB': 'GCA_000404785.1'
'BacteriaBP': 'GCA_000404785.1'}
```

You could achieve this by doing:

```
original_dict = {'GCF_001999625.1': ['bacteriaA'],
                 'GCA_000307585.2': ['BacteriaC', 'BacteriaJ', 'BacteriaK'],
                 'GCA_000404785.1': ['BacteriaB','BacteriaBP']}
new_dict = {}
for unknown_bacteria, known_bacteria_list in original_dict.items():
    for known_bacteria in known_bacteria_list:
        new_dict[known_bacteria] = unknown_bacteria
```

Then you could simply use the pandas replace function:

```
df["unknown"] = df["accession"].replace(new_dict)
```